# Rearranging a name in excel

Tags: excel, substring, vba

In Excel 2010, I have a column of names in the format: "Last, First MI" (<--edit, no comma after first name)

I'd like to have a macro that removes the MI from the string. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
Sub FirstNameFirst()
Dim theName, firstspot, secondspot, finalName As String
Dim oCell As Range

For Each oCell In Selection
    firstspot = InStr(theName, " ")
    secondspot = InStr(firstspot + 1, theName, " ")

    oCell = Mid(theName, 1, secondspot - 1)
Next oCell
End Sub
```

I've learned that you can't do string manipulation like that on a Range datatype. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way would be to use `InStrRev`:

```
Sub test()
    Dim oCell As Range, i as Integer

    For Each oCell In Selection
        i = InStrRev(oCell, " ")
        If i <> 0 Then
            oCell = Left(oCell, i - 1)
        End If
    Next oCell
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! We're getting there... your code leaves simply the last name.

Comment: @AnalyzeThis, just tested it again and it works fine. Note, I'm using `InStrRev`, but not `InStr`

Comment: Ah, yes... this makes much more sense now. Things don't translate perfectly from Acces to Excel. Thanks so much for your input  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Split` to separate the names parts into an array and then just index it to get the result you need:

```
Sub FirstNameFirst()
Dim cl As Range, arr As Variant
    For Each cl In Selection
        arr = VBA.Split(cl, ",")
        cl = arr(0) & "," & arr(1)
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Alex. Thanks for the quick input. Your proecdure is just adding an extra space after the comma.

Comment: Hmm. On Excel 2010 an input of `"Last, First, MI"` returns `"Last, First"`. I have amended the code above as it does add an extra space!

Comment: You know what? My goof... my data doesn't have the second comma. It should just be "Last, First MI" I'll append my Original Post